# gracefully stop thread from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsthread

I have a class which inherits `NSThread`:

header:

```
@interface MyService : NSThread {
  -(void)startMe;
}
```

implementation:

```
@implementation MyService
  -(void)startMe {
   [self start];
  }
@end
```

In another class, I get a instance of `MySerivce`:

```
MyService *service = [self getMyService];
[service startMe];
...

// here, what is the best practice to gracefully stop the service thread ?
```

How can I gracefully stop service thread after it has been started?

Comment: Will you delete this question when someone answers?

Comment: Did you check out other SO answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413955/how-to-cancel-exit-stop-execution-of-thread-object-or-thread-running-in-backgrou

Comment: @Droppy , I delete my previous question because: 1, no one answered it, 2. I noticed it is not a valid question since the code snippet I posted is running fine though it was not previously for some reason which I don't know. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I answered it.  And then you deleted it.

Comment: @Droppy , I don't want to argue on that, but if there is an answer, and I press "delete" button, there would be a pop up saying something "there is an answer, you can't delete it". I didn't encounter that. The only thing I have seen was a comment asked me "why you inherits NSThread?". I probably missed your comment when delete it.