# CRASH - setImageWithURLRequest:~

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uiimageview

I'm using this function for downloading some images in looping `for(int i=0;i<images.count;i++)`.

```
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
              placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * __nullable response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * __nullable response, NSError *error))failure;
```

When images still downloading, I touch back from navigation, app get crash (Crash due to signal: SIGTRAP() at 193e73fb0).

What should I do? So even downloading is not completed yet, I tap back `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`, app will not crash.

Or maybe there are alternative way to do this?

Thanks before.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413955/how-to-cancel-exit-stop-execution-of-thread-object-or-thread-running-in-backgrou) here is a link try it, may be help you.

Comment: @matt I think you don't need any information again. because the crash come when image still downloading.

Answer (score 0):

for (int i=0;i<[img count];i++)

{

nsstring *obj=[img objectatindex:i];

[imgOffer sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:obj]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]
                                     options:0];

}

You can use SDWebimagecache and import this file #import "UIImageView+WebCache.h" to your viewcontroller